# Subscribe to a search results

Tags: feature-request, search, subscription

I have several projects on CocoaControls that are starting to be used in the wild. And that means people will ask questions about them on Stack Overflow. (They're not big enough to warrant tags.)

A good way for me to contribute to SO is to search for these projects and see how I can help.

Requesting search notifications (a la Google Web Alerts) so I can find these questions.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is processor intensive. Yes I would rather have delayed or daily/weekly results than nothing. Yes I can do this anyway with a scraping third party tool.